# How do I reconnect a client when server is down in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, client, server, reconnect

I have a server that accepts sockets from whenever a client connects. I want to be able to shutdown my local server and let my client try to reconnect for about 5 times, and if I start my server the client should indicate that you have reconnected again.

I understand somewhat that this is done in the `try{}   catch(IOException){Here goes the code for handleing reconnect}` I want to use the same socket that I first used to connect. I don't want to create a `new Client` cause then I have to enter username and stuff like that all over again

I tried to creating a new socket like `clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", portnr)` but I don't know if this is the correct way to go. If you have examples that answers this please link them. I dont mind reading as long as it is good documented. Thanks in advance!

EDIT.
Here is my Client Class

```
public class Client {       

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Client client = new Client();
    client.connect();
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

//METHOD CONNECT
//------------------------------------------------------------    
private void connect(){
    int reConnectTries = 0;
    Socket clientsocket;
    try {
        //------------------------------------------------
        //Sets up variables needded for execution            
        clientsocket = new Socket("localhost", 8900);
        DataOutputStream OUT = new DataOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());            
        ListenforMessages listen = new ListenforMessages(clientsocket);
        //We don't want to enter username all the time
        //So this goes not in the while-loop
        //------------------------------------------------
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter username");
        String username = keyboard.nextLine();
        //Sends username to sever so it can be added to a list
        OUT.writeUTF(username);
        //------------------------------------------------

        //------------------------------
        //Creates a thread to listen on messages from server(Other clients in this case)
        Thread trd = new Thread(listen);
        trd.start();
        //------------------------------            
        while (true) {   

            try {
                String sendMessage = keyboard.nextLine();
                OUT.writeUTF(sendMessage);                    
                OUT.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Could not send message to server. " + e);
            }
        }           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldnt establish a connection: " + e);
    }        
}
//------------------------------------------------------------    

//CLASS FOR HANDLEING INPUT. We create a class for input on a new thread
//This is cause we don't want it to block other processes.
//----------------------------------------------------------------    
class ListenforMessages implements Runnable{

    Socket mySocket;
    DataInputStream IN;
    public ListenforMessages(Socket X) throws IOException {
        this.mySocket = X;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            IN = new DataInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
            while (true) {                    
                System.out.println(IN.readUTF());   
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't fetch message from server.Error: " + e);                
        }            
    }

}
}
```

Comment: 1. Same Socket: So in your Client, create a Socket using the null constructor, and use the `connect` method to connect to server. Then, if you are disconnected, you can just use `connect` again. 2. User login data just once: Capture this information on the client-side, and programmatically log them into the server after connecting

Comment: You mean `Socket clientSocket = new Socket()` then `clientSocket.connect("localhost", portnr)` ? How will I use connect to reconnect again?

Comment: I don't understand the question Bojje. You do it the same way you connected the first time

Comment: Want me to add code ,so hopefully that can make better sense?

Comment: Oh now I understood what you meant. Seeing as what I want is something that I have to implement myself.

My problem is that my client gets accepted with a username, no problem. But the thing is that I want the client to connect with the same name.

Comment: @ControlAltDel You can't reuse a socket that has been used for a failed connect.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Could you possibly drop and example? Not sure how I can implement `connect` without creating a new client object

Comment: @EJP Is that true? What is the workaround to this? If there's no workaround, it would seem that this would put a limited life on any Java app that needs to use Sockets.

Comment: EJP you are correct. I answered my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033947/java-socket-reuse/29034409#29034409

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of solutions to this problem, but a simple one would to be have the client try to reconnect (open a new connection to the server) at set intervals. For example, you could try something like this to have your client try to reconnect once every 3 minutes:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", portnr);
        break; // We connected! Exit the loop.
    } catch(IOException e) {
        // Reconnect failed, wait.
        try {
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(3);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            // Interrupted.
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the client will try to connect, and if it fails, wait for 3 minutes before trying again.

Comment: Yeah But if I just open with a new socket I want to go back to the client who disconnected. I dont want to create a new Client object if I reconnect.

Comment: That's not something for which provisions have been made in TCP. If you want to be able to suspend and restore sessions even after disconnects, it's something you'll have to implement yourself as part of a protocol.

Comment: @Bojje How you code and reuse your `Client` objects is your concern. Nobody is forcing you into any specific usage. But you do have to create a new `Socket.`

Comment: @EJP I edited in my client class in the question. I was thinking that doing a while-loop in the first try-catch statement if I can't connect to server, and use a `new Socket("localhost",portnr)` untill I can connect. However I don't know how to go from there. I don't want to create a `new Client` if I connect. Cause If I do I have to re-enter a new username. Then it becomes a whole new client and I don't want that.

Comment: @Bojje You're creating exactly one `Client` object, in the `main()` method; then you're calling Client.connect(). Putting a loop inside the `connect()` method does not constitute creating another `Client` object. You're not making sense.

Comment: @EJP No sorry about my horrible explination. What I meant was if I get a `IOException` like I can't connect to the server in the first `Try-catch` statement, then in that catch-block I have to create a while-loop that creates a `new Socket` that tries to reconnect. And if everything works out fine then I exit the for-loop and that catch-codeblock. However after this is done I don't go back to my `connect` function. The program is done after that..I don't want that. I want it to go back to the `connect (){while-loop}`and use the variables from the first time I created the client object.

Comment: If you get a communication failure, fell the user and call `connect()` again. I fail to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.NoRouteToHostException;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

final class TCPClient{

    private static Scanner in ;
    private static DataOutputStream douts;
    private static OutputStream outs;
    private static InputStream ins;
    private static DataInputStream dins;
    private static String ip;
    private static Integer port;
    private int count = 0;
    private static int times;

    public TCPClient(){
        serverConTest(port);
    }

    private boolean portIsOpenOrNot(String ip, int port){
        try{
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip,port),500);
            socket.close();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void serverConTest(int port){

                while(true){
                    try{
                        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr,port);
                        Socket socket = new Socket();
                        System.out.println("Connecting To server...");
                        socket.connect(sockaddr);

                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        boolean isactive = true;
                        if(portIsOpenOrNot(ip,port)){
                            outs = socket.getOutputStream();
                            douts = new DataOutputStream(outs);
                            System.out.println("Sending Request to server:");
                                while(isactive){
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                                    douts.writeUTF("Are you Alive..!");
                                    ins = socket.getInputStream();
                                    dins = new DataInputStream(ins);
                                    System.out.println("Response from server : "+dins.readUTF());
                                }
                        }

                    }catch(SocketException e){
                        System.out.println("Connection lost");
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        break;
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        System.out.print("connection timeout in 50 second.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter ip : ");
        ip = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Port : ");
        port = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TCPClient();
            }
        });

        try{
            future.get(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){

        }catch(ExecutionException e){

        }catch(TimeoutException e){
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

> This sample will give you the complete understanding that when the server restarts then client will reconnects.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt read all your code but this one is working for me

And dont forget to add the Server class and the method send that sends messages...

Client :

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
static Socket sock=null;
static DataInputStream in=null;
static DataOutputStream out=null;
static boolean connected=false;

static String currentip="";
static int currentport=0;  

static void refreching(){

try {
    in=new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    out=new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

    Thread gg=new Thread() {
        String msg="";
    public void run() {
        while(connected) {
        try {
            msg=in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(msg);

        } catch (IOException e) {
           connected=false;
           System.out.println("Reconnecing...");
           while(!connected)
           connect(currentip,currentport);
        }
      }

        }
    };
    gg.start();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Problem while reading incoming and outgoing"+    
    "messages!");
    connected=false;

            }
}

static void connect(String iphost, int port){
try{
sock=new Socket(iphost,port);
currentip=iphost;
currentport=port;
connected=true;
refreching();
System.out.println("Connected!");
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Cant connect !");
connected=false;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
connect("127.0.0.1",1234); //Example you can enter another's computer ip 
                          //adress if connected to the same network !!!
//Send(Message_To_Server); Dont forget to add the sending code!!!
//Maybe i'll upload a video one day==>how to create a chat application
}
```