# Java Socket Reuse

Tags: java, sockets

member EJP commented on my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018269/how-do-i-reconnect-a-client-when-server-is-down-in-java?noredirect=1#comment46302530_29018269), saying that you could not reuse a Socket that has had a failed connection. I have a tremendous amount of respect for EJP, however, my response is that I find this amazing... If this is true, it would seem to put a severe restriction on the lifespan of any Java app using Sockets - eventually you'd run out, right?

Can anyone clarify the situation, or point to workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured this out: EJP, you are absolutely correct about this

The issue is with `Socket.close()` the Java Socket object cannot be reused after this, and since closing either the Input or the OutputStream is going to call close (as per the Javadocs) this is the end point for this object.

However, it seems like it is absolutely possible to create a new Socket object and `bind` it to the same native socket. The native socket should hopefully have been released by the Java Socket, and be available for reuse, or?

K thanks all for consideration

Comment: I think your mistake is that you're defining 'socket' to be a synonym for 'port', and that's probably not correct. Also, his comment is in reference to an instance of the Java class `Socket` rather than an abstract socket.

Comment: @JamesKPolk This was quite a while back, so I don't remember what I was thinking. But I think what you conjecture as far as my misunderstanding was what I probably was misunderstanding

Comment: You might wonder how I got here. I was wondering what happened to EJP's account and I ended up here.